# Query coming up as null running with Apollo. I'm not sure if it's a resolver or schema issue

Tags: axios, schema, apollo

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but when I run my query on graphql I keep getting null.

This is my resolver:

```
Query: {
    getCountryData: (parent, args) => {
      return axios
        .get(`https://thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          res.data;
        });
    },
  },
};
```

This is my schema

```
gql`
  extend type Query {
    getCountryData: getCountryData
  }
  type getCountryData {
    countrytimelinedata: [countrytimelinedata]
    timelineitems: [TimelineItem]
  }
  type TimelineItem {
    date: String!
    new_daily_cases: String!
    new_daily_deaths: String!
    total_cases: String!
    total_recoveries: String!
    total_deaths: String!
  }
  type countrytimelinedata {
    info: Info
  }
  type Info {
    ourid: String!
    title: String!
    code: String!
    source: String!
  }
`
```

This is my query

```
{
  getCountryData{
    countrytimelinedata{
      info{
        code
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if I'm structuring something incorrectly. I've tried another schema where its the below instead and regardless, it still comes up null.

```
extend type Query {
    countrytimelinedata: [countrytimelinedata]
    timelineitems: [TimelineItem]
  }
```

Thank you for the help and sorry if it's blatantly obvious, still really new to graphQL

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like I did the classic promise handling error. I needed to explicitly return the res.data object

```
Query: {
    getCountryData: (parent, args) => {
      return axios
        .get(`https://thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
         return res.data; <<<< add return here
        });
    },
  },
};
```